# JQuery mobile - enable form element on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

So I have created a website and now I am trying to create a mobile version of the site with jQuery mobile, later using phonegap

The problem I am having is on my form, in the website version, when I change an element on the form the next form element becomes enabled but I can not get this to work on the JQuery Mobile version

Working code for this here (website):

JS

```
if (fname!=="")
{
  document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].disabled=false;
  event.returnValue=false;
}
else if (fname=="")
{
  document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].disabled=true;
  event.returnValue=false;
}
```

html:

```
<p>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <label>First name:</label>
       </td>
       <td> 
           <input name="fname" type="text" required id="fname" placeholder="Enter your First Name" onmouseleave="validateonchange()"  />
       </td>
   </tr>
   <p>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <label>Last name:</label> 
          </td>
          <td>
              <input name="lname" type="text" disabled="disabled" required id="lname" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" onmouseleave="validateonchange()"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
   </p>
```

and the code I'm trying to get working (JQuery Mobile):

html

```
 <form name="MobileForm" onSubmit="return mvalidateForm()" method="post";>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="textinput">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textinput" id="fname" onChange="mvalidateForm()" class="required" value=""  />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="textinput2">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textinput2" id="lname" onChange="mvalidateForm()" value="" disabled  />
    </div>
```

JS

```
function mvalidateForm()
{ 
    var fname = document.forms["MobileForm"]["firstname"].value;

    if (fname!=="")
        {
            document.forms["MobileForm"]["firstname"].disabled=false;
            event.returnValue=false;
        }
    else if (fname=="")
    {
        document.forms["MobileForm"]["firstname"].disabled=true;
        event.returnValue=false;
    }
}
```

Any help into were I am going wrong will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please fix your title. There is never a situation when typing an entire sentence in uppercase is actually appropriate, here or anywhere else in life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery Mobile textinput widget's **[enable](http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#method-enable)** and **[disable](http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#method-disable)**:

```
function mvalidateForm()
{ 
    var fname = $.trim($("#fname").val());
    if (fname && fname.length > 0) {
        $("#lname").textinput( "enable" );
        event.returnValue=false;
    }
    else  {
        $("#lname").textinput( "disable" );    
        event.returnValue=false;
    }
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rc4dwomu/1/)**

#### P.S.

You might want to use onKeyUp instead of the change event.